# Can this task for phrases be called lemmatization?

Tags: nlp, preprocessing, text

I want to 'lemmatize' phrases to [dictionary entries](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+one%27s+mark+on). For instance, the following collocates can be standardized to the idiom in the aforementioned link `leave (one's or its) mark on (someone or something)`:

1. leaving their mark on a country
2. left his mark on me
3. leaves their mark on him
4. left its mark on me

and etc.

One more illustration for [`be in line with`](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+in+line+with):

1. is in line with
2. be in line with
3. are in line with

I don't have a corpus of the standardized phrases as candidates for the process.

I have tested using [lemmatization approaches in Python](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/lemmatization-examples-python/) and found that lemmatization cannot fully meet the requirements here. I wonder which task in NLP most relates to this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is? Yes, the problem certainly requires lemmatization but probably not only, because you still need to capture the exact expression from the text afterwards. This looks like [detection of multiword expressions](https://aclanthology.org/W17-1704/), depending on what is your input data.

Comment: The inputs are as those numbered listed. @Erwan

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem then? You say that "lemmatization does not apply" but lemmatizing the 3 cases in the 2nd example gives exactly "be in line with". The first example requires a bit more work probably.

Comment: @Erwan I have updated my question: 1) does not apply -> cannot fully meet the requirements; 2) adding the question: `I wonder which task in NLP most relates to this problem?`

Comment: But do you have a list of possible dictionary entries then? Because imho it's going to be very hard to obtain 'leave (one's or its) mark on (someone or something)' with placeholders from simple examples.

Comment: @Erwan No fixed result candidates

Comment: Then I think that your task is not defined clearly enough, hence your question: the first example is complex, the expected output has placeholders (e.g. *someone or something*) which cannot be found with simple lemmatization of course. But the second example is simple and the expected output requires only lemmatization. Imho you need to consider the problem of placeholders: how can they be automatically determined? there's no standard task or library for this.